# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token error for store circle object in variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to store the circle object in the canvas in a variable and I getting an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.
What am I doing wrong?

```js
var circle1 = { ctx.beginPath()
ctx.arc(100, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true)
ctx.fillStyle = "FF6A6A"
ctx.fill()
ctx.stroke()
};
```

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

Comment: Objects are key/value pairs. You’ll need a key first before the value e.g. `path: ctx.beginPath(), fill: ctx.fill()` etc

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but that is not valid syntax at all (which is what the error is telling you). And when you draw things to a canvas, you don't get an "object" as a result; you get colored pixels on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A path is a sequence of lines. The 2D canvas interface takes a
>   peculiar approach to describing such a path. It is done entirely
>   through side effects. Paths are not values that can be stored and
>   passed around. Instead, if you want to do something with a path, you
>   make a sequence of method calls to describe its shape.

Reference: https://eloquentjavascript.net/17_canvas.html

So you can put all in functions and create a representation:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')

if (canvas.getContext) {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  const drawCircle = function({ color, x, y }) {
     ctx.beginPath()
     ctx.arc(x, y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true)
     ctx.fillStyle = color
     ctx.fill()
     ctx.stroke()
  }
  
  const drawer = function(figures) {
    for (const figure of figures) {
       figure.drawer(figure.params)
    }
  }
  
  const circle1Spec = {
     drawer: drawCircle,
     params: {
       color: '#FF6A6A',
       x: 100,
       y: 50
    }
  }
  
  const circle2Spec = {
     drawer: drawCircle,
     params: {
       color: '#FF0000',
       x: 220,
       y: 50
    }
  }
  
  drawer([ circle1Spec, circle2Spec ])
} else {
  // canvas-unsupported code here
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```